# How may I workaround this failure of alpha?

Tags: opengl, processing

[image]
[image]

How may I work around this failure of density to sum depending on the Z-order?

```
void setup() {
  size(600, 480, P3D);
}

void draw()
{
  background(0); 

  translate(width/2, height/2);
  stroke(color(255,255,255),128); // 50% alpha
  strokeWeight(130.0);

  point(0,0,0);
  point(-100,0,1); // density sums http://i.imgur.com/NfFv9SJ.png - expected
  point(100,0,-1); // density does not sum http://i.imgur.com/Eyq2qdZ.png - unexpected
}
```

Tested on V3.

Comment: I think you have your comments backwards. The second `point()` is the one on the right that behaves unexpectedly. The third `point()` is the one on the left that behaves expectedly. Interesting question though.

Comment: Processing.js does something similar, although it renders its huge points as squares instead of circles. [Here](http://sketchpad.cc/6JdbnxJve9) is a sketchpad you can play with.

Comment: "I think you have your comments backwards" Thanks - fixed.

Comment: "it renders its huge points as squares instead of circles" Thanks for the warning. It useful to have a reminder of the kind of reason I avoid processing.js :)

Comment: Like I said in one of your other questions, the fact that Processing.js draws them as squares isn't really a bug. It's not well-defined what shape a pixel should be after you magnify it 130 times. I could see arguments for circles or squares. Btw I've added the [tag:opengl] tag to your question, maybe somebody with an OpenGL background can explain what's going on in a way you understand.

Comment: "Did you ever get this sorted out?" No.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem as [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37971321/873165).

I explain it in more detail in your other question, but remember that Processing is using **depth buffering** to determine when **not** to draw pixels that are behind already drawn pixels.

Let's say you're drawing two points: one at `0,0,0` and another **in front** of the first one at `0,0,100`. Here's what OpenGL does:

- Gets the request to draw the first point at `0,0,0`
- Sees that nothing has been drawn yet, so draws that point.
- Gets the request to draw the second point at `0,0,100`
- Sees that the first point is **behind** this new point, so draws this new point.

That's why the left point works. It's in front of the middle point, and you're drawing it afterwards.

But if you have the opposite case, again two points: one at `0,0,0` and another **BEHIND** the first one at `0,0,-100`. Here's what OpenGL does:

- Gets the request to draw the first point at `0,0,0`
- Sees that nothing has been drawn yet, so draws that point.
- Gets the request to draw the second point at `0,0,-100`
- Sees that the first point is **in front of** this new point, so **skips drawing** this new point.

You have a mix of the first case and this second case in your code. You draw the center point, and that draws fine. You then draw the left point **in front of** the center point, and that works fine. But then you try to draw the right point **behind** the center point, and that doesn't work. **You have to draw things from back to front.**

This becomes more obvious if you use different colors:

```
  //red middle
  stroke(255, 0, 0 ,128);
  point(0,0,0);

  //green left front
  stroke(0, 255, 0 ,128);
  point(-100,0,1);

  //blue right back
  stroke(0, 0, 255 ,128);
  point(100,0,-1);
```

[image]

Here we see that you draw the red point in the middle, and then draw the green point in front of it, which works. You then try to draw the blue point behind it, which doesn't work. OpenGL sees that it has already drawn a red point in front of the blue point, so it skips over it.

This works for opaque objects, but it doesn't work for transparent objects, which is why you're having so much trouble. **You have to draw things back to front.**

Normally you could just use `hint(ENABLE_DEPTH_SORT)`, but that won't work in this case. These might look like circles, but they aren't. They're **pixels** that you're making huge. This is also why Processing.js draws them as squares instead of circles- this isn't really a bug, since you could make the case for "a pixel blown up 130 times" being either a square or a circle. Anyway, it appears that Processing doesn't sort the subpixels of a pixel for you.

You have three options:

**Option 1:** Stop using transparency. This is the cause of all of your problems.

**Option 2:** Do the sorting yourself. If you draw the pixels from the back to front, your problem goes away:

```
  //blue right back
  stroke(0, 0, 255 ,128);
  point(100,0,-1); 

  //red middle
  stroke(255, 0, 0 ,128);
  point(0,0,0);

  //green left front
  stroke(0, 255, 0 ,128);
  point(-100,0,1);
```

[image]

**Option 3:** Do the embiggening yourself. You're relying on `strokeWeight()` to draw huge points. This isn't working, because Processing's built-in sorting algorithm doesn't handle this for you. Instead, draw the big shape yourself using more regularly sized pixels. There are a bunch of functions in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/) for building 3D shapes.

Comment: You'd sort of think a graphics-oriented language would have got such basics right by version 3, no? Fingers crossed for version 4.

Comment: @ChrisJJ This isn't really a Processing issue. It's an OpenGL issue. And it's working exactly as it was designed. I agree that its behavior isn't exactly obvious, but it's not really a bug either. I'd be curious to hear why I'm being downvoted though. I thought your questions were good, and I thought I was answering them pretty well. I'm guessing it's because you don't **like** the answer, but that doesn't make it not true. Hey, I didn't design OpenGL! Don't take it out on me!

Comment: "And it's working exactly as it was designed." If you're suggesting processing is working as intended here, then I'd like to see evidence to back that claim. I see nothing in the processing documentation to indicate this behaviour is intended.

Comment: @ChrisJJ I've answered you several times now, showing you OpenGL documentation that shows this is exactly how it's designed to work. If you think this is a bug, feel free to file a bug report, but I've tried explaining that it's not. But if all you're going to do is ignore me and downvote my answers because you don't like the reality of the situation, I'll spend my time elsewhere. Good luck.