# How can I avoid this failure of semi-transparency on intersecting high-detail spheres?

Tags: processing

```
void setup() {
  size(600, 480, P3D);hint(ENABLE_DEPTH_SORT);
}

void draw()
{
  background(0); 
  translate(width/2, height/2);  fill(color(255,255,255),84);
  strokeWeight(0);
  sphereDetail(60);
  translate(-40,0,1);sphere(80);
  translate(2*40,0,0);sphere(80);
  // Fails with lightening absent: http://i.imgur.com/1OmcHvL.png
}
```

fails, giving

[image]

rather than lightening on the left side of the midline too, as expected.

How can I fix this?

A clue may be that changing to

```
translate(2*40,100,0);sphere(80);
```

gives

[image]

Note: Please do not mistake this question as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968944/how-can-i-avoid-this-corruption-on-depth-sorted-semi-transparent-objects).

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
 hint(DISABLE_DEPTH_TEST);
```

This has no side effects in this case, but undoubtedly will in others.