# How to draw a transparent sphere using PShape?

Tags: processing

With Processing 4, I'm able to draw an opaque sphere OK, but a transparent sphere `PShape` looks wrong.

Opaque fill (OK):

[image: opaque solid-color sphere]

Transparent fill (bad):

[image: transparent solid-color sphere with artifacts]

Opaque texture (OK):

[image: opaque checkerboard sphere]

Transparent texture (bad):

[image: transparent checkerboard sphere with artifacts]

Transparent fill using `sphere()` instead of `PShape` (OK):

[image: transparent solid-color sphere]

```
int which;
PImage img;
PShape sphere;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500, P3D);
  colorMode(RGB, 1.0);
  noStroke();
  hint(ENABLE_DEPTH_SORT);   // fixes case 5 (transparent fill with sphere() function)
  hint(DISABLE_DEPTH_TEST);  // breaks cases 0 and 2, somewhat improves but doesn't fix cases 1 and 3

  sphere = createShape(SPHERE, 150);
  
  which = 5;
  if (which == 0) {
    sphere.setFill(color(0, 0.55, 0.67, 1));
  } else if (which == 1) {
    sphere.setFill(color(0, 0.55, 0.67, 0.5));
  } else if (which == 2) {
    img = loadImage("opaque-checkerboard.png");
    sphere.setTexture(img);
  } else if (which == 3) {
    img = loadImage("transparent-checkerboard.png");
    sphere.setTexture(img);
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  lights();
  translate(width/2, height/2, 0);

  if (which <= 3) {
    shape(sphere);
  } else {
    if (which == 4) {
      fill(0, 0.55, 0.67, 1);
    } else if (which == 5) {
      fill(0, 0.55, 0.67, 0.5);
    }
    sphere(150);
  }
}
```

Guessing that the problem might be related to back-face culling, I tried adding —

```
  // import processing.opengl.*;

  PGL pgl = beginPGL();
  pgl.enable(PGL.CULL_FACE);
  pgl.cullFace(PGL.BACK);
  endPGL();
```

— but I don't think it actually affected the OpenGL settings. It may be that I didn't add it to the correct point in the program (tried a few places in `setup()` and `draw()`) or that it's not the right way to enable culling. I tried changing `PGL.BACK` to `PGL.FRONT` just to see if it was doing anything, and the output didn't change. Anyway, I don't know if the problem is related to back-face culling or not.

What would cause the sphere to render like this? And how would I go about fixing it?

**Update (2023.03.10)**

Based on Rabbid76's answer and a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968944/how-can-i-avoid-this-corruption-on-depth-sorted-semi-transparent-objects), I did some further testing and updated the code above.

I noticed that I get different behavior if drawing the sphere with `sphere()` instead of `PShape`. Since I do need a texture, not just a solid color, I would like to get this working with `PShape`.

Possibly a clue to why it isn't working: When I draw an opaque sphere with `DISABLE_DEPTH_TEST`, it has artifacts similar to the transparent sphere —

[image: opaque solid-color sphere with artifacts]

Answer (score 1):

If you draw transparent objects, you must disable the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test):

```java
hint(DISABLE_DEPTH_TEST);
shape(sphere);
hint(ENABLE_DEPTH_SORT);
```

Note that the drawing order of the primitives is not defined. If the depth test is enabled, the parts of the backfaces where the frontfaces are already drawn are discarded by the depth test.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. If I modify my code to use `sphere()` instead of `PShape`, then `ENABLE_DEPTH_SORT` does fix the problem. However, it doesn't fix it for the `PShape` in my original code, which I think I need in order to set a texture on the sphere. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

The TextureSphere example in Processing seems to work OK with a transparent texture if I add `hint(ENABLE_DEPTH_SORT)`.

[image]

This example doesn't use the `SPHERE` `PShape`, but instead does the `vertex()` and `normal()` calls to create the sphere. Presumably I could refactor it into a `PShape` or at least a class.